# Why pandas cannot read my column name in excel? How to solve this problem?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, debugging, error-handling

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-51-afc09c056d5a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Jamie Tsoi/OneDrive/Desktop/FYP/office hourly.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jamie Tsoi/OneDrive/Desktop/FYP')

  File "C:\Users\Jamie Tsoi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Jamie Tsoi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Jamie Tsoi/OneDrive/Desktop/FYP/office hourly.py", line 128, in <module>
    PM10_data['PM10']

  File "C:\Users\Jamie Tsoi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\Jamie Tsoi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'PM10'
```

this is the error message shown. i've check with the letters and spacing but still error.

if you need the excel and codes for reference please comment below

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the output of `PM10_data.columns` ?

Comment: PM10_data= pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Jamie Tsoi\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\ToUG_Office.xlsx",'PM10')
PM10_data=PM10_data.dropna(axis=1,how='any')

PM10_data.max()

PM10_data.isna().sum()

PM10_data['PM10']
PM10_data.columns = PM10_data.columns.str.strip()

PM10_data['PM10']=pd.to_numeric(PM10_data['PM10'])

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn' 
PM10_data['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(PM10_data['Datetime'])
PM10_data.set_index('Datetime',inplace=True)

Comment: the output is some garbled codes

Comment: The error may be in the first line, what do you want to do with 'PM10' after the comma in `pd.read_csv` ?

Comment: to read the specific sheet in an excel file.

Comment: First of all this is an excel file an not a csv, so you need to use `pd.read_excel` instead of `pd.read_csv`. Then, to specify the sheet you want to read data from, use `sheet_name='PM10'`.